# How to track amount of users going from url1->url2->url3?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I am wondering whether it's possible to track the amount of users
who go from url1 -> url2 -> url3 on my website.

This might be a pretty basic question, but I really couldn't figure it out so far.

I don't have direct access to my websites source code because it is hosted by an external provider. (Google Analytics is enabled though, I can see the data google.com/analytics)

Therefore, it would be great if there is an option where I don't have to add code.

Hope somebody can help me.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use custom segment with sequences: include sessions where Step1 was url1, Step2 was url2 etc. In the right of window (see screenshot) you will see number of users.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also set this up as a funnel. Go to admin, click Goals and set it up as a Destination Goals with url3 as the conversion and url 1 and url 2 as funnel steps. It won't be back-dated, but it will track it from the time you set it up.